# disable overwrite existing files

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

i have a requirmet to disable the "overwrite existing files" checkbox on sharepoint 2010

i am following this article but i dont have access to <<< Navigate to C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\Layouts\upload.aspx >>> as this is on a server which i dont have access to. I do however have sharepoint designer and i am the site admin.

i can browse on sharepoint designer on File -> Pages mysite/Style Library/Forms/Upload.aspx
and mysite/FormServerTemplates/Forms/Uploads.aspx but these do not contain a checkbox in the code.

i see from [this site](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/13f0f8f2-e174-4171-946f-f1097bc2e704/doclib-upload-files-checkbox-change-default-to-not-overwrite-existing-files) that i need to be on the server to edit the files but i do not have this level of access.

Any ideas as to how i get to this file?

[Disable Checkbox](http://lazysharepointadmin.com/blog/2011/08/25/change-overwrite-existing-files-behavior/)

Answer (score 2):

**1.**
Please take a look at [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/75382/16290) Stack question. It points to a [tutorial blog](http://sharepoint4u.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/how-to-disable-overwrite-exisintg-files-in-a-library/) on how to do this.

In SPD open `default.master`, then add the script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    var form = $('form');
    if ( form.attr('action').indexOf('YOUR 36 character List ID - Without Braces') > -1 )
        {
        var checkbox = $('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl03_OverwriteSingle');
        checkbox.removeAttr('checked');
        checkbox.parent().hide();
        var multiple = $('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl03_UploadMultipleLink');
        multiple.hide();
        }
    }
);
```

**2.**
 There is another question on Stack [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/47783/16290), where Falak Mahmood suggests that manually changing the Upload.aspx in 12/14 hive is not recommended. Instead, he suggests:

> ...to write a custom Feature which has AdditionalPageHead delegate
>   control to un-check the "Overwrite existing file" (using jQuery)
>   option while uploading the documents.

Comment: Same goes for modifying the OOTB master pages, you should make a copy and edit the copy instead.

Comment: that great help guys but microsoft should make this a configurable feature. Sharepoint is missing so much of this basic simple functionality that its not funny.

Comment: True that. There are a multitude of options that MS should have thought of. That`s why there is customer feedback and 'till they implement some, there are always communities like this one to help each other out. :)