# Checkbox uncheck in document upload form for specific library

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, document-library, file-upload

I want to change the behavior of the document library upload form i.e. it should appear unchecked when the user uploads the document in library.

I searched over the internet and found [this](http://sharepoint4u.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/how-to-disable-overwrite-exisintg-files-in-a-library/) which seems useful as per my need.

I opened the site in the SharePoint designer and edited `default.master` master page put the script but not working in my case.

Script is as below under the `<Head>` section :

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    var form = $('form');
    if ( form.attr('action').indexOf('E2290DED-2B70-4B33-B3A3-97809B209551') > -1 )
        {
        var checkbox = $('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl03_OverwriteSingle');
        checkbox.prop('checked',false);
        checkbox.parent().hide();
        var multiple = $('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl03_UploadMultipleLink');
        multiple.hide();
        }
    }
);
</script>
```

What should I do to accomplish this?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line

```
checkbox.prop('checked',false);
```

to

```
checkbox.removeAttr('checked');
```

Comment: Thanks for reply sir,

I made changes according to your suggestion but the check box is not getting unchecked.

Comment: Verify that you got the right ListId (could get this by going to List Settings and getting the Id from the URL). Maybe try to add an alert inside the If block

Comment: I am getting the ListId from settings url like [this](http://i.imgur.com/pJjU3nC.png) way, is this true? or should I follow other method.? @Per Jakobsen

Comment: That's the right one. By the way you say you modified default.master, is that the one used on your site? Usually it's v4.master. Check 'View Source' of your pages to verify that your JavaScript is included

Comment: Ok, I am checking..

Comment: No Sir, I am not finding the javascript included int the source of the page... I am editing the `default.master` page should I change other page?

Comment: You want to go to 'Site Master Page Settings' `http://bipc11:1234/sites/publishing1/_Layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx`. Here you can see which 'System Master Page' you're using. That's the file you want to modify.

Comment: Thanks sir, I checked the master page and the default master page I was using was `nightandday.master` page I put that script inside it but still not working.

Comment: `nightandday.master` is usually used for 'Site Master Page' (the first) and `v4.master` as 'System Master Page' (the second) the upload page uses the `System Master Page` try changing `v4.master`

Comment: Thanks, thanks a lot sir... It works perfectly.. @Per Jakobsen