# Uncheck "Overwrite Existing Files" from document library upload form

Tags: 2010, document-library, file-upload

I have multiple document libraries in my sub-site.

I want to uncheck the check - box appears on the upload form.

Whenever user uploads form the form should appear with the check box unchecked.

I referred [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47781/set-overwrite-existing-file-unchecked-by-default-when-uploading-document) article but not helped me.

How should I do? Please provide any reference site or help..

Comment: Please check this , it may helpful to you.
[Clickhere](http://www.dotnetsharepoint.com/2016/08/uncheck-overwrite-existing-files-in.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have done this - it's simple once you know how, just search for "OverwriteSingle" inside Upload.aspx:

\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\Upload.aspx

Note this is SP2013 but same should apply in SP2010, just change the 15 above to 14.

Make a copy for backup so you can revert back to it if nec, then change the Checked="true" to Checked="false":

```
<td><asp:CheckBox id="OverwriteSingle" Checked="true" Text="<%$Resources:wss,upload_document_overwrite_file%>" runat="server" CssClass="ms-upload-overwrite-cb" /></td>
```

That should do the trick! HTH, Phil.

Comment: Will it be useful to un-check in specific library?

Comment: No - because it's the upload.aspx page itself, it will apply right across the system. Your post didn't state you need it on a per-library basis (just that you had multiple libraries, like most folk), I don't know best way to achieve that, maybe you should open another Question specifically for that case, someone may know a good way through client script, event receiver etc.

Answer (score 0):

Without customzing Upload.aspx page, we can uncheck the checkbox and modify the contents of "Overwrite existing file" for a specific library using below steps:

1) Create a js file and refer it in master page.

2) Note down the GUID of library.

3) Add the below code in js file.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if (location.href.indexOf('2C63AAA5-BC95-41E4-A199-B7658F44736B') >= 0)
{       $('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl05_OverwriteSingle').prop('checked', false);  
        $("label[for='ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl05_OverwriteSingle']").text("My Custom"); 
}   
});
```